# FireBird Embeddable Server Issue

Tags: java, php, database, sharing

I want to run two application of a single window system but I want the two application to share thesame embedded database.

I was reading the firebird embedded server on windows description and they mentioned some things which I don't understand, please help me clarify:

"You can have multiple embedded servers running at the same time, and you can have multiple apps connecting to the same embedded server. Having a regular server already running isn't a problem either. However, an embedded server locks a database file for its own exclusive use after successful connection. This means that you cannot access the same database from multiple embedded server processes simultaneously (or from any other servers, once an embedded server has locked the file)."

Source: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ufb-cs-embedded.html

Does it mean that the two application can share a single embedded database?

Answer (score 0):

No, they can't. The sentences here tell you that:

> However, an embedded server **locks a database file for its own exclusive use** after successful connection. This means that **you cannot access the same database from multiple embedded server processes simultaneously** (or from any other servers, once an embedded server has locked the file).

The first connection to the database by an embedded server will lock the database; any other process or instance of an embedded server won't be able to access it.

Comment: What does this statement mean: "you can have multiple apps connecting to the same embedded server?"

Comment: It means you can have multiple applications connecting; just not at the same time.